# laptop's webcam shows blank screen

Tags: drivers, webcam

I just format my entire laptop using a bootable USB stick *(I do this when my laptop becomes laggy)*. My webcam was working perfectly fine before that, but after the format, it has stopped working, so I would like to think it isn't a hardware issue. *I have no clue how to debug this issue, any help would mean a lot!*

---

On opening cheese, I get a blank dark screen, notice how all buttons are disabled. The flashlight beside my webcam is on.

[image]

---

output of `ls /dev/video*`

```
/dev/video0  /dev/video1
```

---

output of `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

---

output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:e009 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:0b09 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. SPCA2085 PC Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

output on running `gucview`. Again, the flashlight beside my webcam is on.

```
V4L2_CORE: Unable to find parent usb device.GUVCVIEW: version 2.0.6
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
```

---

output of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

```
# This file lists those modules which we don't want to be loaded by
# alias expansion, usually so some other driver will be loaded for the
# device instead.

# evbug is a debug tool that should be loaded explicitly
blacklist evbug

# these drivers are very simple, the HID drivers are usually preferred
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd

# replaced by e100
blacklist eepro100

# replaced by tulip
blacklist de4x5

# causes no end of confusion by creating unexpected network interfaces
blacklist eth1394

# snd_intel8x0m can interfere with snd_intel8x0, doesn't seem to support much
# hardware on its own (Ubuntu bug #2011, #6810)
blacklist snd_intel8x0m

# Conflicts with dvb driver (which is better for handling this device)
blacklist snd_aw2

# replaced by p54pci
blacklist prism54

# replaced by b43 and ssb.
blacklist bcm43xx

# most apps now use garmin usb driver directly (Ubuntu: #114565)
blacklist garmin_gps

# replaced by asus-laptop (Ubuntu: #184721)
blacklist asus_acpi

# low-quality, just noise when being used for sound playback, causes
# hangs at desktop session start (Ubuntu: #246969)
blacklist snd_pcsp

# ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a
# nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010)
blacklist pcspkr

# EDAC driver for amd76x clashes with the agp driver preventing the aperture
# from being initialised (Ubuntu: #297750). Blacklist so that the driver
# continues to build and is installable for the few cases where its
# really needed.
blacklist amd76x_edac
```

Comment: Does `id` show that you're in the `video` group? [Edit] your Question to add information, don't use Comment.

Comment: @waltinator I am not in my `video` group, and `cheese` works just fine.

Comment: A silly thing to check, but does your laptop have either a privacy shutter or a disable webcam switch or a disable webcam hotkey? If so, make sure it didn't get activated.

Comment: Is the hardware older? `env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/cheese`

Comment: What is the make and model of your laptop and what is your setting at GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=

Comment: @nobody I got (cheese:247977): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 16:31:02.889: gst_element_message_full_with_details: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed.

Comment: @darth_epoxy it cannot be the case in my opinion. My webcam was working perfect a week back, infact I was on ubuntu 20.04 only. I had too many things installed on my laptop, felt it was getting slow, so just reinstalled ubuntu from the boot disk.

Comment: I meant, open a terminal and type `gedit /etc/default/grub` then report back to us what text follows GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=    Because your issue is most likely a driver and we might be able to prove that.

Comment: @darth_epoxy GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" and GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="". I have pasted the enitre output here for you - https://pastebin.com/aw5w1JBn

Comment: Try adding `nomodeset`after quiet splash and let us know if you need help doing that. The other thing to try is turniong off secure boot because it may be preventing the necessary drivers from loading at boot.

Comment: please consider moving your comment to an answer, this actually worked for me!!
I made GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset" and used https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS to disable secure boot

Comment: So - another "silly suggestion" - just got some 20 minutes hunting, even going down to a reboot - just to findout the  notebook I am using has a   physical switch to cover the sensor - check the answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296971/camera-showing-black-in-ubuntu-18-04-on-a-lenovo-l490

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding nomodeset after quiet splash in your GRUB will fix it for now (retrosepective answer).
Save the file and use update-grub to make the change permanent.
Also, turn off secure boot because it may be preventing the necessary drivers from loading at boot.
Here is a [link to help you disable secure boot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS)

Comment: could you explain how to do that exactly?

Comment: Open a termial and type`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` then tell us what text currently lies to the right of GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=

Answer (score 4):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Do  `ls -l /dev/video*`

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/video0"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

Comment: thanks...but this didn't work for me...everything is still the same..

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with cheese on ubuntu - 20.04. The camera blink was on and there is complete black screen in cheese.
Tried below:
Virtual Machine Settings -> Usb Controller -> Change the Usb Compatability under Connection to  USB 3.1/1.1 . Both worked for me. Initially, it was by default set to USB 2.0

Answer (score 1):

I know this sounds stupid, but it's worth a try.

Some laptop models have a physical shutter, so the reason for the black screen is because the shutter's closed.

You can usually open it with a finger by sliding it to the right/left.

Answer (score 0):

Another silly thing to check.  When you have cheese open, go to the Preferences and check your sliders for Brightness, Contrast, Saturation, and Hue.
[image]

If they are out of position, please move the sliders to the reference position in the middle.

Comment: this isn't the issue, thanks though...

Comment: Have you ruled out an issue with the USB port by plugging the webcam into a different USB port?

Comment: my webcam is "built" into my laptop...

Comment: Try running `tail -f /var/log/syslog` in an open terminal, then launch the cheese app.  I just tried that on my laptop and I got output - but in my case everything is working.

Comment: @TBr here is the output - https://pastebin.com/g11JJm1h

Comment: I just activated cheese on my laptop - I don't see this line in your output : `org.gnome.Cheese[233405]: ../src/intel/isl/isl.c:2023: FINISHME: ../src/intel/isl/isl.c:isl_surf_supports_ccs: CCS for 3D textures is disabled, but a workaround is available.`  IMO it looks like the "cheese process" doesn't complete.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that there was no `/dev/video` in my computer.  I then tried creating a symlink `ln -sf /dev/video0 /dev/video`  and changing permissions with `chmod a+rw /dev/video*` and I got the camera back in Zoom.