# Camera Not Recognized in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, camera

My laptop has an integrated web cam.  It worked in previous versions of ubuntu.  Under 20.04, when I run cheese, it says "No device found".  Here is the output of `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`:

```
erik@laptop:~$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.
```

How can I troubleshoot this?

**Edit**: I added myself to the `video` group, this did not fix the problem.

**Edit #2**: As requested in comments:

```
erik@laptop:~$ sudo /bin/ls -l /dev/video*
/bin/ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory

erik@laptop:~$ sudo lshw -class video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 resolution=1920,1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:146 memory:6000000000-6000ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
   
erik@laptop:~$ sudo v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.
```

**Edit #3**:

Output of `lsusb`:

```
erik@laptop:~$ lsusb | grep -i camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b649 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Chicony USB2.0 Camera
```

Partial output of `sudo journalctl -b 0`:

```
Aug 07 22:37:59 laptop kernel: usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Aug 07 22:37:59 laptop kernel: usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b649, bcdDevice=54.03
Aug 07 22:37:59 laptop kernel: usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
Aug 07 22:37:59 laptop kernel: usb 1-7: Product: Chicony USB2.0 Camera
Aug 07 22:37:59 laptop kernel: usb 1-7: Manufacturer: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
Aug 07 22:37:59 laptop kernel: usb 1-10: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Aug 07 22:37:59 laptop kernel: usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0025, bcdDevice= 0.02
Aug 07 22:37:59 laptop kernel: usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Aug 07 22:37:59 laptop kernel: hid: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
Aug 07 22:37:59 laptop kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
Aug 07 22:37:59 laptop kernel: usbhid: USB HID core driver
Aug 07 22:37:59 laptop kernel: input: PixArt USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:093A:2510.>
Aug 07 22:37:59 laptop kernel: hid-generic 0003:093A:2510.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PixArt USB Optical Mouse] on us>
```

**Edit #4**: As advised in the comments below, I followed the answers to this question:

[laptop's webcam shows blank screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368305/laptops-webcam-shows-blank-screen)

The top answer says to do `ls -l /dev/video*`, this is my output:

```
erik@laptop:~$ ls -l /dev/video*
ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory
```

I'm supposed to change permissions on that directory, but it doesn't exist.

The accepted answer says to add `nomodeset` in grub, I tried that.  i.e. in file `/etc/default/grub`, I edited this line...

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

...and added `nomodeset` at the end.  Then I rebooted, the problem is still there.

Comment: Are you a member of the `video` group? `id` will show which groups yoa have membership in.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me.  I was not a member of the `video` group, I added myself, this did not fix the problem.  The output of `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` remains unchanged.

Comment: You must logout/login or read `man newgrp` to make group changes take effect.

Comment: I did.  I logged out and logged in, and the `id` command now confirms that I belong to group `video`.  The problem persists and the output of `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` remains unchanged.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Try `sudo /bin/ls -l /dev/video*` and `sudo lshw -class video` and `sudo v4l2-ctl --list-devices`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Done, thank you.

Comment: Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: I grabbed what appears to be the relevant output from `sudo journalctl -b 0` and added it to my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laptop's webcam shows blank screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368305/laptops-webcam-shows-blank-screen)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I edit my OP with additional details.  Thanks for the suggestion.  My problem differs from the other one in that for me Cheese displays the error "No device found".