# How can I capture Sony Handycam output via USB?

Tags: usb, video, capture

I have an old Sony DCR-TRV250 NTSC handycam that works, and has USB streaming.  I own a handful of old Hi8 tapes with some short family videos on them that I would like to save to my PC so that I can sell or give away the old handycam.

I have turned on USB streaming on the camera itself.  I do not own a firewire cable.

Plugging the USB connector into my PC does show up:

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 054c:00c0 Sony Corp. Handycam DCR-30
```

I've tried using various tools (cheese, obs-studio, kdenlive, etc) but I can't seem to find the magical series of clicks and checkboxes in order to successfully get the data in any form from the camera to the computer. I've scoured the interwebz via Google, and there are a variety of old results from (for example) 2005, but they either aren't applicable, or they just don't work (so far).

Comment: Please [edit] your Question and show us what groups you're in: `id`, and `ls -l /dev/vid*`. For your information, watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you connect the camera.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laptop's webcam shows blank screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368305/laptops-webcam-shows-blank-screen)

Comment: I had a Sony camera in that same series. While it used the popular Hi8 tapes, it stored data digitally, in a (now defunct) format called [Digital 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital8). The good news is that your data is already digital, you just need to copy it off; you'll get lossless originals instead of webcam stream. Pay the few bucks for a firewire adapter/cable, and use a DV-capable editor to copy the files off (I used http://avcutty.de/).