# Integrated camera detected but displaying black on Ubuntu 21 04

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, webcam, camera

I have Ubuntu 21 04 installed on a Lenovo ThinkPad T14 Gen 2i and my integrated camera stopped working. It is detected but just showing black.

My kernel version is:

`5.11.0-40-generic`

My integrated camera is displayed in the output of `lshw`:

```
              *-usb:2       
                   description: Video
                   product: Integrated Camera
                   vendor: Azurewave
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: usb@3:4
                   version: 60.04
                   serial: 0000
                   capabilities: usb-2.01
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

The output of `lsusb` shows on it:

`Bus 003 Device 005: ID 13d3:5406 IMC Networks Integrated Camera`

Output of `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`:

```
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3
    /dev/media0
    /dev/media1
```

And the permissions of these files are:

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Nov 23 15:43 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Nov 23 15:43 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 2 Nov 23 15:43 /dev/video2
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 3 Nov 23 15:43 /dev/video3
```

I have tried changing the permissions of `/dev/video*`.

An external camera works.

Also in `Software & Updates > Additional Drivers` there are `No additional drivers`.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Also in `Software & Updates > Additional Drivers` there are `No additional drivers`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This laptop has a [Webcam privacy shutter](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpadt/t14-g2-(intel)/22tpt14t4n2?org)
Since the screen is black It sounds to me like that is the issue.
Did you verify that it's open?

Comment: Yes, it was the privacy shutter! I did not know about this setting. Thank you very much!

Comment: here is how you can see where the privacy shutter is located and how it works: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296971/camera-showing-black-in-ubuntu-18-04-on-a-lenovo-l490

Comment: I thought there was something wrong with my Laptop, with Ubuntu or with Wayland, but no, turns out I'm just stupid, lol.

Comment: Where is this shutter? How to disable it?

Comment: I have Lenovo Thinkpad T440S and the camera suddently disappeared/stopped working. Is there a privacy shutter in T440S?